# Boys' Love novel where the main character is reincarnated into a beastkin world

Tags: story-identification, novel, isekai, reincarnation

When he was reincarnated, he turns into a baby and is taken in by a cat guy. Overtime, as the main character gets stronger, he grows up in a rapid manner too.